# How to moved folders from one domain to the other in the same server

Tags: linux

Hello very one I need help to find and moved all .wmv files in many folders in my server to just one see what I have so far

```
scp -P 1122 "*.wmv" -type f /home/user/public_html/HOTVIDEOS    \
user@somesite.com:/home/user/public_html/latino/members/HOTVIDEOS/videos
```

who can show me the correct comand please. and thank you very much..

server said:

```
*.wmv: No such file or directory
-type: No such file or directory
f: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

`scp -P 1122 /path/to/videos/*.wmv user@server:/path/to/server/videos/` should move all .wmv files from the local folder to the server.

You can't just mix and match options from other commands (-type f won't do anything in scp)

Comment: LOL thank you very much that show me how to moved the ones in a main folder.  do I need scp to find all .wmv in any folder so dont know if I can use find to have the script to look in the subfolders fro all files .wmv to have it moved I make the mistake of adding each video in a subfolder now I have over 2000 folders each with one or more videos need to take them all out and together in just one.

Comment: @Danny Sanjurnny - try looking at [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync), too

Comment: rsync is good. You could do something like `find . -name *.wmv -type f -exec scp {} user@server:/path/on/server/videos/ \;` or something similar to that. Not able to test it right now.